# Unable to Disable a simple trigger within a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a simple trigger `Trig_SP_History_Delete` in my database which I want to disable with a call from within a stored procedure - like this:

```
-- Stored procedure for SP_Testing
Use DW_dataBase
GO

-----------------------------
-- Create Simple stored procedure
ALTER PROCEDURE stage.SP_Testing
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC('USE [DW_dataBase];DISABLE TRIGGER Trig_SP_History_Delete ON DW_dataBase;');
END;

-----------------------------
-- Execute stored procedure

EXEC stage.SP_Testing;
```

I get an error:

> Cannot find the object "DW_dataBase" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

I have that database, and all permissions, still I get this error. Why is it so?

Comment: Why do you need to `USE` the database in the query?

Comment: Do you really want that, whilst your stored procedure is executing, any other connection that interacts with the table with the trigger will not cause it to fire? That's usually not desirable. Also, you should *avoid* prefixing stored procedure names with [sp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql#arguments)

Comment: @DavidG Exactly !!! You pointed out that silly mistake. It should be a TableName instead of DB..Thanks Buddy

Comment: Sounds like something has gone wrong in the design if you need to disable a trigger from a stored procedure.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Oh how I wish MS would ship a version of SQL Server that outright prevented the `sp_` prefix...

Comment: @marc_s I will follow them.. Thanks for your Suggestions .